# Filter Django Form Field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two form fields I need to filter on and not sure how to. For example, in my forms.py file, I create two fields as such:

```
field_1 = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': "input-field",
    'id': "field-1",
    'type': "text",
}))

field_2 = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
    'class': "input-field",
    'id': "field-2",
    'type': "text",
}))
```

In my HTML, I'm trying to filter by Id, but not sure I can do what I want to:

```
 {% for inputfield in fields %}
     {% if inputfield.id == "field-2" %}
            {{ inputfield }}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

The filter on inputfield.id does not work. Is there a way to filter so that I present only the field I want?

Answer (score 1):

Send `form` object to your html in context. so you can easily render the field you want without any hardcoding

```
{{ form.field_2 }}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not creating my form with Django, but I think I can implement this in a similar way